# Sending RPC calls asynchronously

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc

I have ubuntu server running Bitcoin core v0.16.

I'm sending RPC calls asynchronously using Guzzle (PHP library), but, e.g., if I'm importing 1000 address using `importmulti` command, any further requests are waits until that command finish.

Even though I have set `rpcthreads=100
rpcworkqueue=50` and I've powerful server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`importmulti` is a completely blocking RPC call, no amount of CPU power or RPC threads will prevent it from being blocking. You need to create applications which do not use this command if it is an option.

Comment: Do you think that if I imported each address separately using guzzle (to send it asynchronously) will `rpcthreads=100`, `rpcworkqueue=50` have the effect?

Comment: No, the RPC blocks the entire `bitcoind`, it can't even respond to network connections during this time.

Comment: Shouldn't we disable wallet locking especially when we're importing watch-only addresses? https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/12858

Comment: No, as watch only keys still require a rescan.